# GRUB menu customization (change menu appearance)

Tags: centos, grub

In my GRUB (GRUB 0.97) menu the selector became invisible (changed of inversion color). I would like get my selector bar back and by the way customize a bit grub menu to be more fancy with colors. Where i could change the default b&w schema? Do i need add directives in `/etc/grub.conf` ? or rather use some tool to change grub menu appearance?  In fedora repo i found grub-customizer-3.0.4 but i use centos and it seems the only way is to change grub files manually.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just install using yum install grub-customizer.

If not try this [Grub customizer for CentOS](http://pkgs.org/centos-6/russian-fedora-free-updates-i386/grub-customizer-2.5.7-1.el6.R.i686.rpm.html)